history.replaceState() causes user media video to became black on iOS 17
I have a case, when I need to update a browser's URL while a user is streaming video from an iPhone. I update the URL like this.
window.history.replaceState(null, "", browserUrl);
On iOS 17 it causes a user media video to became black. See an attached video.
I can't reproduce it on iOS 16.
Demo code: https://github.com/ivan-banha/safari-video-container-resize/commit/7197fb57e9758c81ff482fab7fe210bcf59f87b0
Demo link: https://ivan-banha.github.io/safari-video-container-resize
Demo video: https://github.com/ivan-banha/safari-video-container-resize/blob/main/assets/safari-replace-url-bug.mp4
STR:

Open the link in mobile safari.
Press the "share screen" button.
When a video from a camera appears, press the "replace url" button.
The video should become black.

Is this a bug in safari or expected behaviour?

Yes, I have the same issue, when using the canvas to display the camera feed. Whenever I use replaceState the canvas turns black for 2 seconds.

Do you know if there is a bug report on the WebKit bug tracker? I could not find.

Not that I could find.
